# Synchronize Redmine database on Linux with Redmine on Windows

Tags: database, synchronization, redmine

Is it possible to synchronize a Redmine database installed on a Linux-server with a Redmine database installed on a Windows-server?

Answer (score 2):

If your Redmine installation is on MySQL:

1. mysqldump for dumping the entire database, and reproduce it to another one
2. phpmyadmin for a web-based interface to do the same as above
3. Master-slave replication to propagate changes from master **downsteam (ONLY)** to the slaves http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication
4. MySQL clustering to do two-way sync. This is exotic in two ways: setting up MySQL to do clustering and Redmine's database may not be designed to resolve conflicts from two sources. Please dont try it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DB problem, not directly a Redmine issue, and it is possible.

My answer is based on the assumption that you just want to export+reimport the tickets, maybe because of migrating?

To have both issue tracker instances working side by side and keep them synced is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

If mysql replication (master-slave/master-master) cannot be done, there are still some options, as mentioned in this thread:
http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/29725

The nicest way may be rubyrep:
http://www.rubyrep.org/